# How to parse JSON objects to list array

Tags: flutter

I have this item and want loop "description" and "id" objects into array list;

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "OK",
  "payload": {
    "items": [
      {
        "description": "test",
        "icon": "",
        "id": 25
      },
      {
        "description": "TEST PACKAGE",
        "icon": "",
        "id": 26
      },
      {
        "description": "TEST PACKAGE 2",
        "icon": "",
        "id": 26
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Model

Item(decription: "" , id: "" );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Item class.

```
class Item {
  String description;
  int id;

  Item({this.description, this.id});

}
```

2. Define fromJson constructor for Item class

```
class Item {
  String description;
  int id;

  Item({this.description, this.id});

  Item.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    description = json['description'];
    id = json['id'];
  }
}
```

3. 

```
  final response = await http.get("YOUR API");
  // Convert response String to Map
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  List<Item> items = List();
  if (responseJson != null && responseJson["payload"] != null) {
    Map payload = responseJson["payload"];

    if (payload["items"] != null) {
      // Convert each item from Map to Item object and add it to the items List
      payload["items"].forEach(
        (v) {
          final item = Item.fromJson(v);
          items.add(item);
        },
      );
    }
  }
```